# HOW to get the Year from a <input type= "date"/> using getFullYear()

Tags: javascript, validation, user-input

I'm trying to calculate the age of the user by subtracting the current year from the user's birth year but I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: birthDate.value.getFullYear is not a function

Here is My Cod

```js
function checkAge(){
            let birthDate = document.getElementById("dateOfBirth");
            let today = new Date();
            let userage = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.value.getFullYear();
```

```html
<label for="dateOfBirth">Date of Birth<strong>*</strong></label>
            <input type="date" id="dateOfBirth" name="D.O.B" >
```

e:

Comment: Nothing in your example calls your function. You're also attempting to call a Date() function on a string.

Comment: `birthDate.valueAsDate`?

Answer (score 1):

birthDate.value will return a string, try this instead:

```js
function checkAge(){
     let birthDate = document.getElementById("dateOfBirth");
     let today = new Date();
     let userage = today.getFullYear() - new Date(birthDate.value).getFullYear();
```